# Check page redirects via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rds

I'm working on RDWeb access solution and wanted to check that the RDS hosts when typed in an Internet Explorer page redirect to `https://rds.ca.org/rdweb`

For example I wanted to check via a PowerShell script if I type `srdshost01` or `02` or `03` or `04` in an IE page it should get me the redirected link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could post an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2.aspx) to the URL using the alternative host name and check wether the response was sent from the redirected URL:

```
$response = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://srdshost01").GetResponse()
$isRedirected = $response.ResponseUri -eq "https://rds.ca.org/rdweb"
```